# Call finish-output from format

Tags: format, common-lisp, bufferedstream

I noticed that there is no
[`format`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_format.htm) directive which would
call [`force-output`/`finish-output`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm).

***Why?***

It does seem to be useful in user interaction, cf.
[Lisp format and force-output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2078490/850781).

E.g., `~=` could translate to `finish-output`, and `~:=` to `force-output`.
I don't think `clear-output` makes much sense in this context, but we
might map `~@=` to it for completeness.

PS. Cf. [CLISP RFE](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/feature-requests/53/).

Comment: Clear-input could maybe be useful with bidirectional streams?

Answer (score 2):

Summary from [comp.lang.lisp](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/z6yYObQjCPM):

## An explanation from Steven Haflich

The language defines no portable way to extend the set of format
directives (other then `~/.../`) but that's not really the issue here.
The real problem is that it is not well defined to call `finish-output` or similar functions at arbitrary places during printing.

If pretty-printing is in progress, the stream received by a
`pprint-dispatch` or `print-object` method may be an encapsulating stream --
one that delays output temporarily until it can make decisions about
white space and line breaks.  (There are also potential problems if
`finish-output` were called inside a `~<` justification, but that directive
is a hairball!)  What would one expect `finish-output` to do if called
inside a pretty print operation?  I don't think it's well defined.

The problem isn't particular to format, of course, but a directive for
`finish-output` from format would just add another sharp edge to the
language.  `finish-output` etc. are only safe to call when completely
outside an actual or implied call to `cl:write`.  Call it as a function
at an appropriate point in your code (where you know execution isn't
inside a nested write) so the intention is clear and you don't mess up
printer internals.

## A suggestion from Rob Warnock

Actually, no changes to [`format`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_format.htm) are needed. Just add this function somewhere in the [COMMON-LISP-USER package](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_ced.htm):

```
(defun fo (stream arg colon-p atsign-p &rest params)
  (declare (ignore arg params))
  (cond
    (colon-p (force-output stream))
    (atsign-p (clear-output stream))
    (t (finish-output stream))))
```

Then:

```
(progn
  (format t "enter var: ~/fo/" nil)
  (read))
enter var: 456
456
```

The problems with this (*portable*!) approach are

- verbosity (`~/fo/` instead of `~=`)
- need to consume a format argument (`nil` in the example above)